# Overriding appsettings values in asp.net core

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am overriding the values which are set in appsettings.json file by configuring them in azure portal.
To do so I have made following changes which are working fine except when I debug my code.

**Startup.cs**

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    Configuration = configuration;

    IConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();

    builder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

    builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();

    Configuration = builder.Build();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    DBContext.ConnectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("Connectionstr");
    Constants.AppLogicURI = Configuration["MailUri:LogicAppUri"];
    Constants.BlobStorageKey = Configuration["BlobKey:BlobStorageKey"];
    Constants.BlobStorageConnectionString = Configuration["BlobConnectionString:BlobStorageConnectionString"];
    Constants.BlobUri = Configuration["Uri:BlobUri"];
    Constants.StorageAccount = Configuration["AccountName:StorageAccount"];
}
```

When I am debugging my code I am not getting any of the values from appsettings.json file due to which application failed to start.

I only get the values if I comment out the line `Configuration = builder.Build();`

Not sure why I need to do this and how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your `appsettings.json` file isn't being read is because you are not calling [`SetBasePath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.fileconfigurationextensions.setbasepath?view=aspnetcore-2.1) on your `ConfigurationBuilder`. This is usually handled for you using `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` in `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder`, which itself is used in `Program.cs`.

Although you could just call `SetBasePath` in your `Startup` constructor, there is no real reason to create your own `IConfiguration` instance when you can just use the `IConfiguration` that is being passed in. This instance is configured already to read from *both* `appsettings.json` and environment variables, with the environment variables overriding those specified in `appsettings.json`.

Any settings you specify in the Azure portal's "Application settings" and "Connection strings" sections will override those specified in your `appsettings.json` file, as they are added as environment variables within the Azure environment.

Comment: So you are saying I should not keep anything in startup constrcutor except configuration single line. Also, by doing settings in azure portal it will automatically override those appsettings value. Correct me if I am wrong. Can you plz provide any example/pseudo code for the same ?

Comment: That's correct - all you need in your constructor is `Configuration = configuration;` - this will allow the Azure Portal settings to override the `appsettings.json` values. Can you be more specific about what example code you are looking for?

Comment: I am looking only to override the appsettings value by setting app settings and connection strings in azure portal. As I need to configure those settings on azure as per environment. This is the whole aim about it.

Comment: That is what will happen with this setup as is. There's no extra code needed.

Answer (score 1):

Change

`Configuration["BlobKey:BlobStorageKey"];`

To

`Configuration.GetSection("BlobKey:BlobStorageKey");`

Because the `Configuration` is `Startup.Configuration` and you have **Build()** in `Program.cs` so you need to comment out `Configuration = builder.Build();`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to build the configuration yourself, the .NET Core code does that for you when you call `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(...)` in `Program.cs`.

.NET Core will configure the different providers e.g. Azure vault, JSON files, environment variables, command line etc.

The only think you need in `Startup` is

```
Configuration = configuration;
```

You already have this at the top of the `Startup` method which is why it works when you comment out the `Configuration = builder.build();` code.

You can find out more about the different Providers and the order in which the variables are read in the [Configuration documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#providers).

**EDIT**

The documentation shows the order of providers that .NET Core automatically adds for you. The last sentence of the section on Providers says:

> This sequence of providers is put into place when you initialize a new
>   WebHostBuilder with [CreateDefaultBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.webhost.createdefaultbuilder). For more information, see
>   [Web Host: Set up a host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-2.2#set-up-a-host).

Take a look at the link to `CreateDefaultBuilder` as that also explains what that method configures for you by default.

Comment: So you mean by commenting that line ONLY it will also override the settings in azure if deployed the web api.

Comment: No. You should remove ALL of the code from `Startup` apart from the first line because .NET Core does the `AddJsonFile` and `AddEnvironmentVariables` (plus a few others including `AzureVault`) for you. Take a look at the documentation link in the answer. Read all of the section that the link points to and it should make more sense.

Comment: Yeah Still its not clear to me.. it means I need to configuration in Program.cs file instead of Startup.cs ? If this so then how the azure environment variable will be overridden with this ? I am referring to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45298562/azure-application-settings-not-overriding-my-appsettings-json-file-values