# appsettings.json files or App Service - App Settings in Azure Portal?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, appsettings

I have so far used the `appsettings.{environment}.json` files to keep application level configuration settings. Now I encounter this tab in Azure Portal for an App Service.

What is the difference between using the `appsettings.json` files and "Application Settings" Tab in the Azure Portal? And which one to use When?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure Application Settings not overriding my appsettings.json file values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45298562/azure-application-settings-not-overriding-my-appsettings-json-file-values)

Comment: @ryanwebjackson I believe it falls in line however, i will keep this question open to see if i get any other responses. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Few reasons to use Azure *Application Settings* -

**1st** - Let's assume that in order to avoid leaking configurations in `appsettings.json`, you aren't committing it to your repo. But you also deploy your web app on Azure AppServices. In this situation **Application Settings** tab can help you to configure your configurations directly and then Azure will auto create `appsettings.json` by reading those values.

**2nd** - This time we are *committing* `appsettings.json` and deployed web app on Azure. We also have a property as

```
{
  "Users": {
     "CanAccessApp": [ "abc@gmail.com", "test@gmail.com" ],
     "CanAccessHangfire": [ "abc@gmail.com", "test@gmail.com" ],
     "CanAccessLog": [ "abc@gmail.com", "test@gmail.com" ]
   }  
}
```

Now, I also want one more user to be able to access logs. How you will do it? Generally, update in your `appsettings.json` and redeploy.

Or you can create similar property in **Application Settings** by

```
Users:CanAccessLog:0 -> vic@gmail.com
Users:CanAccessLog:1 -> abc@gmail.com
Users:CanAccessLog:2 -> test@gmail.com
```

and so on where 0,1,2 are indexes of the array (*Azure style*). This one will help us to test quickly without redeploying or modifying `appsettings.json`.

Answer (score 0):

> difference between using the `appsettings.json` files and "Application Settings" Tab in the Azure Portal? And which one to use When?

If you are using more than one environment like **Production**, **Staging** and **Development** for your application. You need specific Environment ***appsettings*** i.e., **`appsettings.{environment}.json`**.

Or if you don't want to use any specific environment. In this case you are using only **production** (Default) Environment you can use **`appsettings.json`** file.