# Connection string works locally but fails to initialize in Azure

Tags: postgresql, azure, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0, connection-string

This problem is occurring with a Web API project developed with Visual Studio 2022 in C# and.NET6.  The database is PostgreSQL hosted in Azure and I'm using EF Core.  Specifically:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore v7.0.2
Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL v7.0.1
```

I followed the code-first approach to scaffolding the database schema and seeding it with sample data.  That all worked fine locally as well.  Program.cs looked like this:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ContentManagerContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ContentManagerConnection")));
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserDataFeedRepository, UserDataFeedRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserAppRepository, UserAppRepository>();

var app = builder.Build();

// run db migrations
using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var services = scope.ServiceProvider;

    var context = services.GetRequiredService<ContentManagerContext>();
    context.Database.Migrate();
}

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
else
{
    app.UseDefaultFiles();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

The DbContext class shown above is injected into each of the repository classes, which are in turn injected into the controllers.  All dependency injection is a fairly boiler-plate approach.

The connection string referenced above in Program.cs was pulled straight from the database's page in Azure, specifically the "Connection Strings" blade.  I chose the one for ADO.NET and it worked like a charm.

```
Server={my_server};Database={my_database};Port=5432;User Id={my_user_id};Password={my_password};Ssl Mode=VerifyFull;
```

[image]

It was also necessary to add a firewall rule for my local IP address in order to connect to the PostgreSQL database in Azure.

I've had zero issues running the entire solution locally.  The API launches in debug mode in VS2022 and functions normally.  I can call it's controller endpoints via Postman and a React app without any errors.  Data pulled from the database is returned as expected.

Before deploying the API to Azure I added the ADO.NET connection string created by Azure as an Application Setting in the App Services configuration blade.

After a successful publish of the API I got errors calling out the line in Program.cs where EF migrations are applied.  As a temporary work-around, I commented this out:

```
var context = services.GetRequiredService<ContentManagerContext>();
//context.Database.Migrate();
```

That resolved the first error, but then I got errors indicating the database server wasn't accessible.  I had forgotten to add the App Service's external IP addresses (all 7 of them) as firewall rules for the database.  But after completing this step the app service was still unable to connect to the database server.

Researching online I saw that some people have `Ssl Mode=Require` in their connection string whereas I have `Ssl Mode=VerifyFull`.  I changed the connection string in Azure only to be `Ssl Mode=Require` and subsequently got a successful result in the Diagnostics Tools blade -> Check Connection Strings:

[image]

However, even though it's telling me it can connect using the provided connection string, when I make requests to the API I'm immediately getting the following error:

```
Exception: 
System.InvalidOperationException: The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.Open(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnection(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternal(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.InitializeReader(Enumerator enumerator)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.<>c.<MoveNext>b__21_0(DbContext _, Enumerator enumerator)
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
```

I don't understand why Azure would tell me it is able to connect in Diagnostics but then I get a runtime exception saying the connection string couldn't be initialized.

I have tried switching it back to `Ssl Mode=VerifyFull` in Azure, but when I do that, I get this error in the Diagnostics output:

[image]

Currently the only difference between local (where it works) and Azure (where it doesn't) is the `Ssl Mode` portion of the connection string.

Since the Ssl Mode values supported locally and in Azure are inconsistent, I am wondering what else in the connection string is not supported in Azure?  Could it be a forbidden character somewhere, possibly in the password?  The connection string's password has multiple special characters.

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After logging the connection string as seen by the repository classes and finding it to be an empty string, it suddenly hit me where the empty string could be coming from.  Because I keep my local configuration in either appsettings.Development.json or in user secrets within each project, the appsettings.json file has empty strings for each property.  This is necessary because the json structure has to match across all of them.  So it appears that the empty string from appsettings.json was being read instead of the connection string defined in the app service's Configuration -> Connection Strings blade.

I searched for threads about Azure app service configuration failing to override appsettings.json and found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45298562/azure-application-settings-not-overriding-my-appsettings-json-file-values).

In my case, the suggestion to ***change the connection string type in Azure from PostgreSQL to Custom*** fixed it.  My app service is now loading the connection string correctly.

Answer (score 0):

> This error message is due to the connection string property has not been initialized.

1. Also check if the connection string is being passed correctly to the DbContext.
2. Check if the database server is running and able to access it. (Connect to the database server using a tool like pgAdmin or psql to check if the server is running and accessible).

You can also check the Azure portal for any logs or errors related to your PostgreSQL database.

I have used the below NuGets in the code and able to connect the database.

[image]

**Created a database in Azure.**

[image]

**In Local**

[image]

**In Azure Portal**

[image]

> And the error reason might be issue with the server firewall configuration ,client firewall configuration and  connection parameters, such as the server name in the connection string or a missing @servername suffix in the user name.

For further information, refer to the [blog.christian-schou.](https://blog.christian-schou.dk/connect-postgresql-database-to-dot-net-6/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Rajesh.  Following your suggestion, I added some additional logging to output the connection string that is injected into the repository class.  When I check the app service logs, I see the logged message and the connection string is empty.  So this confirms that something is preventing the value stored in the Azure App Service's Configuration -> Connection Strings.  Locally it is being read successfully from appsettings.json.  If appsettings.json is being deployed, would the value stored there override the Application Settings in the App Service Configuration?

Comment: Yes, the value stored in the `appsettings.json` file will override the `Application Settings` in the App Service Configuration. If you want to use the value stored in the App Service Configuration, you need to remove the connection string from the appsettings.json file. Check if the connection string is being overwritten by any other configuration source. Refer to configure [connection strings in Azure App Service](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/app-service/configure-common.md)

Comment: It appears that the 'PostgreSQL' connection string type in Azure is not fully supported.  After changing it to 'Custom', it now overrides the empty string in appsettings.json.  See my full answer below.  Thanks again Rajesh, I needed your suggestions to get me going down the right path.